# Is Fn::Cidr random?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-vpc, infrastructure-as-code

Will Fn::Cidr always output the same values if called with the same input?
I want to obtain 3 sub addresses for three different subnets from the same Vpc ip block, can I guarantee that I'll get different addresses for those 3 subnets if I use them as below:

I'm changing Fn::Select's first argument for each one.

```
"SubBlock1" : { "Fn::Select" : [ 0, { "Fn::Cidr" : ["10.0.1.0/16", 3, 24]} ] }

"SubBlock2" : { "Fn::Select" : [ 1, { "Fn::Cidr" : ["10.0.1.0/16", 3, 24]} ] }

"SubBlock3" : { "Fn::Select" : [ 2, { "Fn::Cidr" : ["10.0.1.0/16", 3, 24]} ] }
```

Comment: This if for IPv6? I don't think you can choose the complete CIDR for IPv6 -- you can only choose _part_ of the IP address range since all IPv6 addresses are "public". Thus, you wouldn't be able to have the same VPC CIDR each time for different VPCs.

Comment: I'm not talking about different VPCs, there are different Subnets in the same VPC. I already obtained an Ipv6 Cidr block  for this particaular vpc in a previous step, the question is how can I can guarantee that i get three different sub-Cidr blocks from this Cidr so I can assign them to 3 different Subnets.

Comment: I suggest you try it and see what happens! The documentation describes `Ipv6CidrBlocks` as "A list of IPv6 CIDR blocks that are associated with the VPC". I wonder if it simply returns the ranges associated with existing subnets? Let us know what you discover.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein i edited the question and simplified the example, my question isn't related to ipv6 or ipv4 but rather to the way Fn::Cidr works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test this, I created a stack with this template:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: 2010-09-09

Resources:

  Bucket:
    Type: AWS::S3::Bucket

Outputs:
  
  Block1:
    Value: !Select 
        - 0
        - Fn::Cidr: 
          - 10.0.0.0/16
          - 3
          - 8

  Block2:
    Value: !Select 
        - 1
        - Fn::Cidr: 
          - 10.0.0.0/16
          - 3
          - 8

  Block3:
    Value: !Select 
        - 2
        - Fn::Cidr: 
          - 10.0.0.0/16
          - 3
          - 8
```

(The bucket is included simply because at least one resource is required.)

The output was:

- Block1: `10.1.0.0/24`
- Block2: `10.1.1.0/24`
- Block3: `10.1.2.0/24`

So, yes, it **will output the same blocks each time** because it is simply dividing the given CIDR as requested.

Some notes:

- I had to supply `cidrBits=8` to generate a `/24` block
- `10.0.1.0/16` in your example is not a valid `/16` block, so I changed it to `10.1.0.0/16`